# How to replace Math.random() with crypto.getRandomValues() and keep same result?

Tags: javascript, random, cryptography

I'am using the following function to get a specific random string to pass it then to another function:

```
function generateRandomString() {
    return Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + 
           Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
}
```

I would like to use `crypto.getRandomValues()` instead `Math.random()`. How would I pass `Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);` as an argument to the `crypto.getRandomValues()`, or I'am in the wrong direction?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the argument for `crypto.getRandomValues()` is a [typed array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray), so, what exactly do you mean as use `Math.random() .... ` as "an argument" ?

Comment: Yes, You're right. Just did find out here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues. And yes, I would like to a random string using the `crypto.getRandomValues()`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
function generateRandomString() {
     return (crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0] / 4294967295).toString(36).substring(2, 15) + (crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0] / 4294967295).toString(36).substring(2, 15);
}
```

Logic:
Divide a random UInt32 by the maximum value (2^32 -1) to get a result between 0 and 1

Here is the reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues

Comment: Great! Doing the same as `Math.random()`

Comment: Glad it could help

Comment: @k.vincent: While this faithfully answers the question that was asked, it is important to realize that your method is not the correct way to obtain a random base-36 string and is not secure, even when using a secure PRNG.